# for /R do del command to delete SPECIFIC files

Tags: cmd, delete-file

I have been cleaning up a bit of files on a 4 TB drive. The problem is, I have a number of files that are duplicates. These duplicates got a number appended to the end of them so they are easy to "find".

But, I need a quick way to delete them without affecting the original files.

for example:

03 Song To Sing By.mp3
03 Song To Sing By 1.mp3

I need to delete ANY that have the 1.mp3

I tried this:

```
for /R C:\MUSICTEST\ %F in (*1.mp3) do del "%F"
```

But it is deleting both files.

Ideas? Thoughts?

Comment: One other method is to create a CRC list of all the files and delete the binary duplicates. With MP3 files this means they would need to have the same header information as well as the music data and be the same file size.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
(
for /R C:\MUSICTEST\ %%F in (*.mp3) do IF EXIST "%%~dpnF 1.mp3" (
FC /b "%%~fF" "%%~dpnF 1.mp3" >nul
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO del "%%~dpnF 1.mp3"
)
)>musiczap.bat
```

This batch should do the job.

For each `x.mp3` found, see whether `x 1.mp3` also exists in the same directory. If so, compare the two and if they are identical, echo the delete line to the 'musiczap.bat' file.

Censoring `musiczap.bat` before running it is up to you.

```
dir /s "c:\musictest\* 1.mp3"
```

should then reveal any remaining `* 1.mp3` files

---

Here's my testing:

Target directory:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 12A3-6FE2

 Directory of c:\musictest

04/05/2013  10:55    <DIR>          .
04/05/2013  10:55    <DIR>          ..
04/05/2013  10:49                 0 03 song to sing at 1.mp3
04/05/2013  10:45                 0 03 song to sing by 1.mp3
04/05/2013  10:45                 0 03 song to sing by.mp3
04/05/2013  10:55                 5 03 song to sing it 1.mp3
04/05/2013  10:55                 5 03 song to sing it.mp3
04/05/2013  10:54                 0 03 song to sing to 1.mp3
04/05/2013  10:54           105,351 03 song to sing to.mp3
               7 File(s)        105,361 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  614,691,926,016 bytes free
```

Result of running batch:

```
del "C:\musictest\03 song to sing by 1.mp3"
```

Note:
  "at" only has a " 1" so not deleted
  "by" is only one where file contents of "name" and "name 1" are the same
  "it" are same length, but different content
  "to" are different length

The file "musiczap.bat" produced needs to be run to delete the files. Probably not a good idea unless you've read it first - especially if you have turned `ECHO` on.

If the batch appears to get stuck then try this modified batch

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
(
for /R C:\MUSICTEST\ %%F in (*.mp3) do IF EXIST "%%~dpnF 1.mp3" (
 echo comparing "%%~fF" "%%~dpnF 1.mp3"
 FC /b "%%~fF" "%%~dpnF 1.mp3"
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO del "%%~dpnF 1.mp3"
)
)
```

Note that this may generate a whole slough of data - but perhaps something is upsetting `fc`.

I you can't see which file-pair is causing the problem, re-append the ">nul" to the end of the `fc` line. This will suppress the `fc` output, but the filenames on which `fc` is getting stuck should be displayed.

Comment: Peter, that batch file doesn't seem to work. I even turned echo on and it just sits there. No files were deleted.

Comment: AH I see. Let me give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

try this (and remove the `echo` if the output is OK:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d C:\MUSICTEST\*.mp3 ^|findstr /ir "[0-9]\.mp3$" ') do echo del "%%~i"
```